# Ansible concat default variable and literal string

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm not able to do a very simple thing.

In my task I'm trying to concat two default variables with a literal string to create a path

```
- name: "Uploading File"
  copy:
    src: "{{ installer_iso_src_location }}"/"{{ installer_version }}"/filename.iso
    dest: /opt/temp/filename.iso
```

This gives me a error. Any idea how to concatenate a variable and literal strings?

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, **YAML**

1. Your syntax must conform to YAML:

   > Strings (scalars) are ordinarily unquoted, but may be enclosed in double-quotes ("), or single-quotes (').

   So you can either write:

   ```
   parameter: value
   ```

   or

   ```
   parameter: 'value'
   ```

   or

   ```
   parameter: "value"
   ```

   The following is not a valid YAML:

   ```
   "{{ installer_iso_src_location }}"/"{{ installer_version }}"/filename.iso
   ```
2. If your `value` starts with a curly brace `{` Ansible will try to parse it as a dictionary (YAML is a supserset of JSON, so a dictionary/associative array enclosed in curly braces is a valid syntax).

   > Associative arrays are represented using the colon space (: ) in the form key: value, either one per line or enclosed in curly braces ({ }) and separated by comma space (, ).

   If it's not a valid JSON array, Ansible will report a syntax error.

Secondly, **Jinja2**:

- The majority of parameters in Ansible (the value of `when` being a notable exception) are Jinja2 templates (strings).

  To refer to an Ansible-variable-value you use a [Jinja2 expression](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#expressions) delimited by `{{` and `}}` (no quotes involved):

  ```
  {{ variable }}
  ```

  There are two ways to concatenate strings with variable values for your case:

  ```
  {{ installer_iso_src_location }}/{{ installer_version }}/filename.iso
  ```

  or

  ```
  {{ installer_iso_src_location + '/' + installer_version + '/filename.iso' }}
  ```

Now, YAML and Jinja2 combined:

- Since your parameter (string) starts with `{` character and it is not a valid YAML/JSON dictionary, the YAML parser will fail (see the point **2.** of the above YAML requirements).

  In result, for your value to be considered a string by YAML parser, you must enclose the value (Jinja2 template) in quotes:

  ```
  src: "{{ installer_iso_src_location }}/{{ installer_version }}/filename.iso"
  ```

  or

  ```
  src: "{{ installer_iso_src_location + '/' + installer_version + '/filename.iso' }}"
  ```

  or other combination of single and double quotes.
- If your parameter value started with a string other than `{`, you could use it without quotes, as in the first example in the point **1.** above.

---

Lastly, there are two notable exceptions where value is not expected to follow YAML rules:

- Ansible shorthand syntax for modules with key-value pairs joined by `=`
- free-form parameter, as for example in the `command` or `shell` modules